# Where can I find good information, tutorials and or examples on relational algebra queries?

Tags: relation-algebra

Taken a break from my personal project and getting some work done. I would like to find some examples, tutorials on relation algebra.

Anything with good examples will be very useful

Comment: This might be better asked in http://math.stackexchange.com . Also, the tags are misleading, how is this related to php, sql, or mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the one i use:
[Relational Algebra](http://db.grussell.org/section010.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest perhaps having a look at the first few of videos from [db-class.org](http://db-class.org). They cover most of what you will need to know including alternate notations and examples. There are also mini quizzes to test you are understanding it and a problem sheet (unfortunately no answers).

Answer (score 0):

There are good tutorials pdf and videos on [Braintem](http://braintem.org/series/view/44004/)